# Pandas DataFrame returns NaN in all cells after applying a filter on the colum names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply a filter on the column names which start with 'Inc' on a pandas dataframe. This returns 9 columns and I am looking for values that contain 'Yes' in all of those 9. Once that is done I would like to return all the rows (and columns) from the df that have 'Yes' in all 9 columns. I tried the following `df[df.filter(like='Inc') == 'Yes']` but it returns all the columns with NaN except for the 9 'Inc' columns.

A very naive method of implementation that actually worked for me, was as follows but is not very scalable:

`df[(df['Inc1_E1_C1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Inc2_E1_C1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Inc3_E1_C1'] == 'Yes')  & (df['Inc5_E1_C1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Inc6_E1_C1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Inc7_E1_C1'] == 'Yes')  & (df['Inc8_E1_C1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Inc9_E1_C1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Inc_4_E1_C1'] == 'Yes')]`

Does anyone have a better way of having this implemented?

[image: This is the output while using the Naive implementation]
[image: This is what I get when using the filter to get all 'Inc' columns and then search for rows that satisfy the 'Yes' condition]

Comment: please include a [mcve] that replicates your issue accurately

Comment: Your filter attempt returns a Boolean DataFrame. You want to check that all of those values in a row are 'Yes', so you need to check `all` across that axis to get a Boolean Series: 
 `df[df.filter(like='Inc').eq('Yes').all(axis=1)]`